# system asking fsck command in manually

Tags: command-line, fsck

This week my system ask to do this `fsck` command to run.

How to I change in this commend in automatically

or How to avoid the problem .

**system in 2GB RAM 160GB HDD and the ubuntu is 15.10**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your server probably wasn't shut down nicely, so the filesystem wasn't unmounted correctly. In such situations you risk having to run fsck manually to ensure filesystem consistency.

Just run `fsck -y /dev/sdxx` where sdx is the disk mention in the text above the prompt.

Comment: i run this comment the system working `fsck /dev/sda1` which one is right